# Plugin for svn that extract text from sources

Tags: svn, plugins

I don't know if a plugin like that exists but for me will be useful. I'd like a plugin that can extract some text (defined in some way similar to Doxygen) and insert this text into description when a commit is made.

With this plugin, I could document the changes of a source file into the source file and then, the plugin would merge all changes into the description text.

Do exists this plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running in a bash environment, you can achieve that functionality with:

```
svn stat | cut -c 9- | xargs -L 1 grep -H "TOKEN" >> comment_file.txt
svn ci -F comment_file.txt
```

You determine what "TOKEN" will be used to tag your documentation lines.  The only issue
will be cumulative comments unless you use a unique token for each commit.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I'm searching a plugin because I'm working in a multiplatform project.However, thanks for the command. It would be useful if you haven't to change the token every commit or you have a way to delete tokens after put in in a file.

Answer (score 1):

As Amardeep said, you can do whatever you like in a script around the svn call. Unfortunately, you can *not* modify the comments, file attributes, etc., in server hooks.

Comment: What do you mean with server hooks? I'm speaking about my working copy and not about code in the server.

Comment: To repeat: Use what Amardeep said – adapted to the different clients you use. “Server hooks” are code (typically scripts) that run on the server to enforce comment or code conventions, to send around mails, to create backups for every submit, to check out every submit to a staging web server etc. I just wanted to add that they are, unfortunately, not usable for this requirement.